# Java Process Builder Command Error, Escaping double quotes

Tags: java, string, escaping, processbuilder

Following statement works fine when typed in CMD

```
wmic /node:IP /user:Someuser /password:PWD Process Call Create "cmd /c echo 'Required_Info' %SystemDrive% %SystemRoot%"
```

I am trying to excecute the same through java process builder. Here is the code.

```
//some code
String wmic_cmd = "Process Call Create";
String wmic2 = " \"cmd /c echo 'Required_Info' %SystemDrive% %SystemRoot% \"";
cmdTokens.add(wmic_cmd);
cmdTokens.add(wmic2);
/*debug and checked the value of cmdTokens array - it was
[wmic, /node:10.0.0.0, /user:Someuser, /password:PWD, Process Call Create,  "cmd /c echo 'Required_Info' %SystemDrive% %SystemRoot% "] 
*/
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmdTokens.toArray(new String[]{}));
Process proc = pb.start();
```

When i check the error stream of proc i get the following -

```
Process Call Create - Alias not found.
```

This indicates a syntax error for WMIC. So Something is going wrong while sending the command string array to process builder.

Any ideas??

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and (continue to) build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your command line and what you want to do, this is not how to do it. Use:

```
final List<String> cmd = Arrays.asList("wmic", "/node:IP", "/user:Someuser",
    "/password:PWD", "Process", "Call", "Create",
    "cmd /c echo 'Required_Info' %SystemDrive% %SystemRoot%"
)

// build processBuilder using cmd.toArray(new String[cmd.size()]) as a command
```

The quotes around the `cmd /c echo etc` are there to prevent the *command interpreter* to separate arguments. No need to replicate them when you pass raw arguments, and this is what you use with a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks...didn't know about the arguments logic in processbuilder.